# In RMarkdown what does three backticks followed by a not braced language name (```yaml , ```r, ```bibtex) mean and do?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I know that three backticks ```` ``` ```` are used to indicate a code block in RMarkdown and if you put a language inside of braces R markdown will try to run it but what does it mean if the language is not in braces?  I can see that Yihui uses ```` ```yaml ````, ```` ```r ````, ```` ```bibtex ```` to cause code blocks to appear with color highlighting [in the RMarkdown book](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-book/blob/master/02-basics.Rmd).  Does anybody know a reference to what that is actually doing and best practices with the notation?  I am thinking it means show (but don't execute) this code block (and indicate the language for anybody who bothers to look into the source).  If that is right, where is it documented?  Does anybody know how to set the color of the words that are rendered inside such a (language named but not braced) code block in a html and/or pdf document?

Comment: Stack Overflow here actually uses the same notation. We call them "code fences". You may be able to find more by searching that.

Comment: Thank you.  That is a good idea.  Unfortunately I tried searching for three backticks, triple backticks and code fence and could not find the right documentation.

Comment: It's common in Markdown. Might be able to find out how it works by reading markdown documentation. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189920/what-is-the-3-x-backquote-markdown-used-for).